# Network discovery on LAN without broadcast

Tags: network-programming, broadcast

**Short version**: How would you recommend going about connecting a client to a server that are on the same local network, without manually entering the ip, when broadcast is disabled?

---

**Further details**: I am working on an educational multiplayer game for children. Many schools appear to be blocking broadcasting for security reasons. The children will be rather young, so it could be difficult for them and error-prone to have to enter the IP manually. They will all be in the same room and will all see the server screen. The game is made in Unity (C#).

---

**Potential solutions**: Here's what I thought about:

- Connecting both the local server and clients to an external server, communicating the local server ip through the clients through the external server, then connecting directly and disconnect from the server. Not ideal because of the extra hosting costs.
- Send a regular UDP message periodically to all ips on the subnet? This will probably be picked up by any decent firewall and blocked though, right?
- Putting a QR code on the server that kids would take a picture of with the client app and have it connect that way? May be more of a hassle.
- Having the server play random tones corresponding to numbers that the client is listening for? (Speakers may not always work though)

Sounds like the first one is the most sane and easy solution. Do you have any other ideas on what someone in this situation could try?

Answer (score 2):

Is UDP multicast possible?
If yes then a common solution is that all participants join the same multicast group and the server listens on a well known port. If a client wants to know the address of the server it sends a packet to the multicast group, which is received by the client and answered with another packet, which then can be used by the client to determine the servers address.
In addition to that servers can also announce their presence in regular intervals by sending a suitable message to the multicast group.

Answer (score 0):

What I can think of is an ad-hoc communication protocol between all the devices. Say you have 1 server and 10 clients. All the devices should run a service(say server-discovery) that binds to a fixed port say 9999. Now any time the client wants to connect to the server and doesn't know the IP, it starts a scan. Loops through different IPs and tries to connect to 9999. If it manages to hit, it asks for the server IP. In case it manages to hit the server it will get the IP since the server knows it's own IP and the client will maintain the server IP in a cache. If the client hits another client. It can ask for the server IP. It the other client knows the IP it will share the info else decline.
I agree there is a lot of overhead, but I think this will be robust unlike sound and would reduce cost of printing QRs everytime.

Comment: Thanks, that could be a good idea so that not every client needs to ping every device.

The QR code would appear on the server screen, so it shouldn't cost anything.

Comment: Oh, if the QR appears on the screen, that should be the perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

on the local network the traffic is direct from host to host.
I don't understand which devices is blocking local broadcasts.

if there aren't too many peers on the LAN ( less then 100 ), I think udp broadcasts work fine and you dont pollute the network.

to have an idea of your "pond", I suggest you to sniff your local traffic.
there are many broadcasts : arp, windows, ipp, dropbox...